Update View elements in SwiftUI
I’m working on a MenuBarExtra where I need to know the id of the front most application. I think I’ve got that working, but I don’t know how to update the view when the application reappears.
Here is a simplified version of what I’ve got.
struct Test: View {
    var body: some View {
        var bundleIdentifier: String = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
        VStack {
            Text(bundleIdentifier)      //  doesn’t change
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            bundleIdentifier = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
            print(bundleIdentifier)     //  correct new value
        })
    }
}

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra("Testing", systemImage: "questionmark.bubble") {
            Test()
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}

What’s the correct method to update the Text view?

No nothing here is telling SwiftUI to redraw. I suggest some basic tutorials

Read the basics of SwiftUI, put @State private var bundleIdentifier: String = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier! outside of the body.

@workingdogsupportUkraine That was it. If you woudn’t mind putting that in an answer I can accept it and close off the question.

don't close the question, it may help someone else in the same situation.

Try this approach with @State private var bundleIdentifier: String ... outside the body of the View.
Example code:
// for testing
class NSWorkspace {
    static var shared = NSWorkspace()
    var frontmostApplication: BundleIdentifier?
    init() {
        self.frontmostApplication = BundleIdentifier(bundleIdentifier: "initial value")
    }
}

// for testing
struct BundleIdentifier {
    var bundleIdentifier: String?
}

struct Test: View {
    
    @State private var bundleIdentifier: String = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(bundleIdentifier)
            Button("Change") {
                bundleIdentifier = UUID().uuidString // <--- here some random text
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            bundleIdentifier = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication!.bundleIdentifier!
            print(bundleIdentifier)
        })
    }
}

